# I am setting permissions in manifest but have to enable manually in `marshmallow`

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions

Here is my manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

This is all I needed for my project but I need it in code, not manually in app settings.

Comment: Provide more details... where you should enable manually ???

Comment: in the app settings there is is option of permission i have to set there permission

Comment: This will help you. You can check whether user selected the checkbox `Never ask again` http://manidesto.github.io/permissions-in-marshmallow

Answer (score 1):

To use the new permission model in Marshmallow, you need to both specify your permissions in the manifest (as you did) AND request the permission at runtime.  Only permissions that are considered as "dangerous" require the runtime request.  Dangerous is defined as:

> A higher-risk permission that would give a requesting application
>   access to private user data or control over the device that can
>   negatively impact the user. Because this type of permission introduces
>   potential risk, the system may not automatically grant it to the
>   requesting application. For example, any dangerous permissions
>   requested by an application may be displayed to the user and require
>   confirmation before proceeding, or some other approach may be taken to
>   avoid the user automatically allowing the use of such facilities.
>   From: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Here's an example of code that checks if you need to request the permission.  (Remember, even if the user grants your permission request, they can later revoke it in App Settings, so you need to check each time you need it.)

```
private final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION=1;

private void requestAccessLocationPermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            showExplanation("Permission Needed", "Rationale", Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, REQUEST_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        } else {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, REQUEST_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission (already) Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
        int requestCode,
        String permissions[],
        int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}
```